# Set certain ancestor to not clip element

Tags: html, css

Given this example:

```
<div class="main">
<div class="container">
  <div id="banner-message">
    <p>I want to be hidden</p>
    <p id="el">I want to be visible</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

the `.main` and the `.container` have `position:relative`, the `#banner-message` and the `#el` have `position: absolute` because I need to move them around inside the `.container` which has `overflow: hidden` with the purpose of hidding all elements that overflow, except the `#el`, and here is my question:

Given this structure and positioning is it possible to make only `#el` visible when it overflows the `.container`?

heres's a fiddle as repro:
https://jsfiddle.net/k5w6stuL/

Comment: the short answer : no ... but if you tell us what you want to achieve we may restruct the code and find another way

Comment: You could using Javascript or jQuery to do some DOM manipulation.

Comment: @TemaniAfif thank you for you quick answer, that was I was expecting to hear, just to confirm. I can't actually restruct the code because this is a repro of a complex and lengthy structure in an angular application with dynamically generated and third-party components.

Comment: @August as I said "Given this structure", this means I can't do DOM manipulation.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, can you include some sort of preview of the behaviour you want ?

Comment: if you are open to hack, here is an idea : https://jsfiddle.net/k5w6stuL/1/

Comment: @ZohirSalakCeNa Given that structure and positioning the `#el` element has to be visible. Or, try to make `#el` visible without changing html structure or css positions and `overflow:hidden` of `.container`.

Comment: The only way I can think of is to use `position: fixed` on your #el, then adding a scroll event to calculate the top dynamically, but that's an ugly solution. Without changing the DOM it is difficult to solve your issue